# How to return the count of duplicate relationships with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I have the following tables `Orders`, `Lamps` and `Lamp_Order` which is a `pivot` table. The `Lamp_Order` table stores the `id` of an `Order` and a `Lamp`. An `Order` can contain multiple of the same `Lamps`. So it could be that there are for example 5 `Lamps` with an `id` of 1 connected to the same `Order`. I want to get the count of the same `Lamps` within an `Order`. So this method or function that I want to make should return 5 in this case.

I currently have this function in my `OrderController` to return the `Order` with the related `Lamps`:

```
public function index()
{
    $orders = Order::all();

    // Get the Lamps for each Order.
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        $order->lamps;
    }

    return response()->json([
        'orders' => $orders
    ], 200);
}
```

The response in my `vue` front-end looks like this:
[image]

As you can see there are some lamps with the same ID being returned. Instead I would like to return this Lamp with the count of how many times it is related to that `Order`.

My `Order` model looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email'
    ];

    /**
     * Get related Image.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function image()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Image::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get related Lamps.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function lamps()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Lamp::class)->withPivot('room');
    }

    public function countSameRelationships()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Detach related lamps when deleting Orders.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function ($order) {
            $order->lamps()->detach();
        });
    }
}
```

I was thinking about creating a function in the `Order` model which I call in the `index` function in the  `OrderController`. Can someone tell me if there is some sort of already existing function to count these "duplicate" relationships? Or what would be a good approach to tackle this problem? I prefer the solution to return the right data directly from the Laravel backend. But if it is also possible to apply some sort of filter function to remove and count duplicate relationships that would be fine as well.

Comment: How are you planning to handle if the order has 5 laps of id 1 and 2 lamps of id 2?

Comment: I handled it as described in my given answer. It works like a charm now @KeshariNandan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, at this moment I made the following solution in my Vue front-end as I didn't manage to solve the problem in my back-end:

```
  removeAndCountDuplicates(order) {
      // map to keep track of element
      // key : the properties of lamp (e.g name, fitting)
      // value : obj
      var map = new Map();

      // loop through each object in Order.
      order.forEach(data => {
        // loop through each properties in data.
          let currKey = JSON.stringify(data.name);
          let currValue = map.get(currKey);

          // if key exists, increment counter.
          if (currValue) {
            currValue.count += 1;
            map.set(currKey, currValue);
          } else {
            // otherwise, set new key with in new object.
            let newObj = {
              id: data.id,
              name: data.name,
              fitting: data.fitting,
              light_color_code: data.light_color_code,
              dimmability: data.dimmability,
              shape: data.shape,
              price: data.price,
              watt: data.watt,
              lumen: data.lumen,
              type: data.type,
              article_number: data.article_number,
              count: 1
            };
            map.set(currKey, newObj);
          }
      });

      // Make an array from map.
      const res = Array.from(map).map(e => e[1]);

      return res;
    },
```

This function increments a counter and adds it to the object. If someone has a solution that works in the back-end I would like to see that answer as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) in laravel:

```
public function index()
{

    $orders= User::with(['lamps' => function($query) {
            $query->select('lamps.id', DB::raw("COUNT('lamps.id') AS lamp_count"));
            $query->groupBy('lamps.user_id');
    }])->get();

    return response()->json([
        'orders' => $orders
    ], 200);
}
```

Comment: I believe I should replace `User` with `Order` here?

Comment: Yes. My bad. Should be Order instead of User

Comment: If you have made an error in a post, please [edit the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60542872/edit) to correct it.